# Job scheduling affecting performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to know about below scenario related to job scheduling in SQL Server(Any version).

I have two SQL server databases placed in the same server. 
Then a Job is scheduled in one database. 
Now, I want to know that job scheduled in one database affect or decrease the performance of other database placed within the same server.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And have you tried some of these standart tools https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179428.aspx?

Answer (score 2):

Yes if your job is cpu or i/o intensive. The same server has to run your job using its resources.

If your job is i/o intensive, you can reduce its effects by putting its data/log files on different disk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It can also happens in high configurable server.
Server where my databases are placed having 32 GB RAM and intel xeon 2.30ghz e5-2699 processor.

Comment: That depends on whether the normal operation of your database requires that much power or not.... we don't know